# Fetching all the accounts from Genache

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I'm using Ganache to generate dummy accounts but every time I try to access the list of accounts using *web3.eth.accounts* or the *web3.eth.getAccounts* method, I only get access to the first account in the array. Can anyone advise on how I can get an array of all the accounts?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I fired up `ganache` and ran `new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')).eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => { console.log(err, accounts); });`, and it displayed multiple accounts.

Comment: Are you using Metamask? It seems like Metamask is picking the first account in the array. When I disable Metamask, I get all the accounts. How can I get all the accounts with Metamask enabled?

Comment: Ah, if you're connected to MetaMask, then you should get the list of accounts in MetaMask.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, how do I get the accounts in MetaMask?

Comment: What you're doing should return the accounts in MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

**For version 0.x of web3:**

try this:

```
beforeEach(()=>{
web3.eth.getAccounts((err,acc)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('error.............',err);
    }
    console.log(acc);
});
});

describe('contract',()=>{
it('deployes a contract',()=>{

});
});
```

or can simply try this :

```
 beforeEach(()=>{
 web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
 });
```

**for version 1.x of web3:**

```
beforeEach(()=>{
 web3.eth.getAccounts()
  .then(fetchedAccounts=>{
     console.log(fetchedAccounts);
  });
});

describe('Inbox',()=>{
it('deployes a contract',()=>{

  });
});
```

version 1.0.0 of web3 uses promises while 0.x doesn't work on promises it works on callbacks.

hope it helps!